# Why are my colors dull in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

So I was drawing and I tried to press the undo fast keys and somehow instead did something that change the color of my lines? (My fast keys are the typical alt, command, z) I was using a color that had a alert on it [image]

So now whenever I chose a color that has a alert, it automatically changes it to the suggested color when I start painting.
When I'm selecting a color it looks right but it's as soon as I try it on my canvas.

I don't want to print this or anything so I want to use a full range of colors. Is there a way to get it to stop doing this?

Comment: Are you working in CMYK or RGB? Did You mistakenly turn on Proof Colors in the View menu?

Answer (score 1):

The warning you have circled in the example means "out of gamut for CMYK" - so I suspect you either changed the colour mode to CMYK, or you are viewing the CMYK proof colours.

Make sure you are in RGB colour mode, and switch off CMYK proofing: CTRL+Y toggles it on or off.